# Acitvity runs on the wrong screen orientation when open it while the mobile is locked

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

I'm building an android application, which has a service, the service keeps running even if the app is killed by the user, I use this service to do some calculations, and send and receive data to the server, sometimes I use this service to relaunch the application, my application uses only landscape orientation. I used this code in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However, when the app is killed by the user, and the user locked the mobile, it works, but it runs in portrait orientation.
I use this piece of code to run the app in the service:

```
   bringToForegroundIntent = new Intent(AppContext.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
   bringToForegroundIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | 
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

   locSaveService.startActivity(bringToForegroundIntent);
```

I tried to solve this issue by deleting portrait `XML` layout from the app, but it throws an exception. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can use setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) in oncreate

Comment: Thanks @Lucky, I already did this, but no luck.

Comment: Did you try to remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. and make an entry in manifest for MainActivity with launchMode:singleTask ??

Comment: No, I didn't, I will try it and inform you :)

Comment: Please read [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)for further assistance and queries

Comment: I tried what did you say, and the same behavior :/, I can't understand why would that happen, while the orientation is landscape in manifest

Comment: show some more of your code like both xml and MainActivity

Comment: Check this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a)

Comment: What part of code do you need to see??

Comment: please read my previous comment

Comment: I checked it out, I tried everything, I'm confused, this case just happens when the mobile is locked.

Comment: let me see the code...